# EditText changes the color into a custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

The following image isn't exactly what I'm developing but can show you the problem.

The `EditText` out of `ListView`:

[image]

And the same `EditText` into `ListView`:

[image]

The `ListView` layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_login"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_txt_user"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textColorHint="#CCCCCC"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_txt_senha"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:password="true"
        android:textColorHint="#CCCCCC"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And finally the `getView()` of my adapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = _layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, viewGroup, false);

        mHolder = new ViewHolder();

        view.setTag(mHolder);

    }
    else {

        mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    return view;

}
```

Anyone knows why is this `EditText` changes the color when I use it into `ListView`?

Comment: why you use listview for login screen

Comment: No, I'm not using. As I said, it's just for test. It's not what I'm developing. There is another thing I'm developing that has the `listview` and the `edittext` into.

Comment: `android:background="@color/yourColor"` why dont you use this if you want to change background of edittextr?

Comment: Because I don't want it with color, I need the `textview` in natural color. I've already tried with transparent color, but doesn't work like I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours I finally found out the problem. I had to remove `getApplicationContext()`.

The code was such as:

```
LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And now is such as:

```
LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```